# how to write a script or function to create, but not execute, a command line

Tags: bash

All,

Can it be done? Can we write something that will assemble a long command line but *not* execute it, just leave it there, either waiting for ENTER, or waiting to be edited?

Comment: May be you want to source a shell script with a function containing a long command line, possibly with parameters, in it. You can then execute that function later.

Comment: @rayandrews : We need a better use case, it is hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish and why. Do you want to type `myFunc` on a users (your?) terminal command line, press enter key, and the result appears, but un-executed, and in the command-line mode for editing? Why, to what purpose? If you can expand on your needs, please edit your original question above and don't reply here ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

my understanding of you needs is:

you want to execute a script/or command, generate another command line, which under your current prompt, so that you can press Enter to fire it or edit something then press Enter.

this is possible if we do some trick with bash `history` command:

```
 echo "this is a really long command">> $(echo $HISTFILE)&& history -r
```

then you press Up-arrow, the text `this is a really long command` will show under your current prompt, and waiting for your "Enter" :)

Note, this will clean your command histories that not yet written to your history file. To peresist those command and append the target cmd `this is a really long command` at the end, you could do:

```
history -a && echo "this is a really long command">> $(echo $HISTFILE)&& history -r
```

hope this trick helps you sovle your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry if my question wasn't clear, however Kent has understood it exactly. It would be more elegant if the generated command was put directly on the command line, however it is not hard to press the up arrow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it to a variable as a string, and it wont be executed:

```
echo "Type a command: "
read CMD

# Or give CMD a string representing a command directly
# CMD="ps -ef"
```

Then to run it:

```
RESULT=`$CMD`
# Or, just
$CMD # by itself will execute the string as a command
```